# "Начеку"

Tags: этимология

"Быть начеку" — значить сохранять бдительность. Но каково происхождение слово, что за "чек"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У меня есть книга В.М.Мокиенко "Образы русской речи", там этот оборот подробно изучается. Автор приходит к выводу, что древний славянский корень -чек- означал "ждать" (родственен корню чаять), а выражение "быть на чеку" -> "начеку" произошло из охотничьей терминологии (как, например, настороже). То есть чек - это охотничья засада.

Comment: Для сравнения: в белорусском есть чакаць 'ждать', в украинском - чекати (с тем же значением).

Answer (score 0):

В сербско-хорватском есть слово "Чека" (Čeka), которое как раз и означает настил для засады для охотника (лабаз).

А вообще слово "чекать" есть и в русских диалектах, и в украинском, белорусском и большинстве других славянских языков. Примеры можно посмотреть в этимологическом словаре Фасмера, правда, надежной этимологии там нет.

Comment: И как это связано? Мало ли какие слова есть в разных языках?!

Answer (score -1):

chekout = проверять результат, ревизировать(глаг.), а chekout counter= касса(стойка за которой ждут, если по смыслу).
Следует предположить, что корень либо заимствован (у койне), либо унаследован от родительского языка. Первый более вероятный (латынь, греческий и др. языки межнационального общения). Второй более интересный (общий индо-арийский язык предок).

Comment: Что за койне-то такой? Что за "родительский язык"? При чем тут английские checkout и checkout counter? Можно поподробней про "индо-арийский язык предок"?))